# Iphone detecting bluetooth devices

Tags: iphone, ios, detection, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing an iPhone app and I need get the nearby bluetooth devices.
I'm using the CoreBluetooth Framework and that doesn't work. I know that this framework is only for Low Energy Bluetooth, so I bought a bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter which support Low-Energy. I'm testing this app in my iPhone 5. This is my code

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{ 
NSString *messtoshow;

switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"State unknown, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered off."];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];
        [mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]] options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey]];

        [mgr retrieveConnectedPeripherals];


        break;
    }               
}
NSLog(messtoshow); 
}   

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:
(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID, advertisementData);
[mgr retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheral.UUID]];
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
NSLog(@"This is it!");
}
```

This print "Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.", but doesn't find my usb bluetooth or any other nearby bluetooth device. I need a solution for this, Im getting crazy.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I ended up in similar problem. Did you find any solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that 180A is the right service?

If not try:

```
[mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey]];
```

Comment: I have tried all the posibles services and I tried setting services as nil too. It doesn't work. I give up, but thank you.

Comment: Did you check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine.  [Search the app store for TI BLE for their free iPhone app.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ti-ble-multitool/id580494818?mt=8)

If their app can not discover your bluetooth device, make sure your bluetooth device is ON and is advertising.